# What is the best antonym for "influencer"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

Which word is the best antonym for "influencer"? For "influencer", I am referring to its [general meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influencer):

> :one who exerts influence : a person who inspires or guides the actions of others

Sample sentence:

> In the era of digital campaign, social media influencers have shown their great power in affecting the decisions of many young voters.

If influencer means someone who has the power to affect decisions of others, how do we call the *people who are being influenced*?

I have tried to use [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/influencer), but couldn't find any good words. "Influencee"? Recipient? They don't really sound right to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Follower*

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/72571?redirectedFrom=follower#eid):

> 1b. A person who obeys or is guided by the teaching or opinions of
> another; an adherent, disciple, pupil. Also: a person who conforms to
> or complies with an example, model, rule of conduct, etc.

Examples of use:

> As a result, an influencer's **followers** are perfectly primed to
> want to buy anything he or she is seen wearing or using. ([How to
> Leverage Social Media for Your Ecommerce Business | BFM](https://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/how-to-leverage-social-media-for-your-ecommerce-business/))
>
> The influencer's **followers** trust what he or she is posting, which
> can boost a brand's reputation in the eyes of its target audience.
> ([Rethinking Instagram Advertising: Instagram Ads vs. Sponsored
> ...](https://fullbottle.co/blog/rethinking-instagram-advertising-instagram-ads-vs-sponsored-influencer-posts))

Comment: Given at previous threads: acolyte / follower /  ... disciple / devotee ... / adherent ....

Comment: OP asked for **the best** antonym to _influencer_ specifically. This is a different question from those you've associated this with.

Comment: 'The best' must be taken in relation to all other possibilities, and is thus over-broad and POB. I'm just trying to prevent yet another duplicate thesaurus subset.

Comment: Hey DW256 and @EdwinAshworth, I have modified my question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571550/what-is-the-best-word-to-describe-people-who-are-influenced-by-something-unwilli). Would love to get some input from you!